# Java List - Best way to insert or replace

Tags: java, collections

So I was wondering what would be the best way to

- perform an insert if an element does not yet exist
- perform an update if an element already exists

Maybe a list is not the best data structure for such a use case?

Comment: A `Set<YourObject>` maybe?

Comment: I find your question to lack essential details. I suggest you add a bit of example code/data. Honestly, I am surprised that a user with your experience writes up a question any newbie would probably be beaten up for ... like: what do you mean by update? Replace the element at a certain index with another object? Or are you talking about a map, and key value pairs? And when we look at the answers coming in, they all make blind guesses what exactly you are talking about. Which is another indication of a lack of quality on the question.

Answer (score 5):

If you want uniqe element use Set insted of list

```
Set<your_object_type> name = new HashSet<>();
```

If you want to update with same value the do

```
name.add(val);
```

If you wand to update with diffrent value then use below code

```
if(name.remove(val1)){
name.add(val2);
}
```

Comment: you should explain how to update elements in the Set

Comment: Even in example code, stay to java naming conventions. There shouldnt be classes with "_" in their name! And I agree, how do you do "updates" of an entry in a set? This answer is a ambiguous as the question ...

Comment: Note that `name.contains` is unnecessary.  `name.remove` returns true if the item was present, false if it was not present.  So, `if (name.remove(val1)) { name.add(val2); }` is sufficient, and has the benefit of doing only one lookup in the collection.

Comment: Note that the `add` method of sets retains the already present element and does not replace the existing element with the provided one on collision. As a result, the sequence of method calls is the same for sets as for lists in this use case.

Comment: If you want to insert or update new elements and remove elements not present in the new elements : use `Set#retainAll`.

Answer (score 1):

I think `ArrayList` would be better option, The `set(E e)`method of `java.util.ArrayList` provides **O(1)** 
time performance for replacement. `remove(E e)` with `add(E e)` is more expensive.

```
List<People> peoples = new ArrayList<People>();
peoples.set(getIndexToUpdate(), new People("Ali", "Lahore"));
```

*You can use this method as long as your `ArrayList` is not immutable.*

while `add(E e)` of `java.util.Set` will not update already existing element as per [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#add(E)).

> Adds the specified element to this set if it is not already present
>   (optional operation). More formally, adds the specified element e to
>   this set if the set contains no element e2 such that (e==null ?
>   e2==null : e.equals(e2)). If this set already contains the element,
>   the call leaves the set unchanged and returns false. In combination
>   with the restriction on constructors, this ensures that sets never
>   contain duplicate elements. The stipulation above does not imply that
>   sets must accept all elements; sets may refuse to add any particular
>   element, including null, and throw an exception, as described in the
>   specification for Collection.add. Individual set implementations
>   should clearly document any restrictions on the elements that they may
>   contain.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "HashSet" and use method "contains" to check if elements already exist or not. If not, you can add desired element. For example:

```
Set<Integer> setOfIntegers = new HashSet<>();
if(!setOfIntegers.contains(23)){
    setOfIntegers.add(23);
}
```

Now you can check if the set contains the desired element, remove it and add another one

```
if(setOfIntegers.contains(23)){
    setOfIntegers.remove(23);
    setOfIntegers.add(50);
}
```

Now your set updated value "23" with the new value "50"

Comment: Yeah, when I define "strange and bizarre" as "great", your answer is really great. Sets do not support the concept of **updating** values. Re-defining the meaning of a word doesn't change that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that adds custom objects of type `Item` to a `Set<Item>` or updates existing ones:

**Item.java**

```
public class Item {

    private String name;
    private int position;

    public Item(String name, int position) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.position = position;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getPosition() {
        return position;
    }

    public void setPosition(int position) {
        this.position = position;
    }

}
```

**Main.java**

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Set<Item> myUniqueStrings = new HashSet<Item>();

        Item a = new Item("A", 1);
        Item b = new Item("B", 2);
        Item c = new Item("D", 3);
        Item d = new Item("D", 4);

        // add some of the items to the Set
        myUniqueStrings.add(a);
        myUniqueStrings.add(b);
        myUniqueStrings.add(c);

        System.out.println("———> Before update:");
        myUniqueStrings.forEach(item -> System.out.println(item.getName() 
                + " at position " + item.getPosition()));

        // update an item that exists in the Set
        c.setName("C");
        System.out.println("———> After update of an item in the Set:");

        myUniqueStrings.forEach(item -> System.out.println(item.getName() 
                + " at position " + item.getPosition()));

        System.out.println("———> After having added a new item to the Set:");

        // add a new item to the Set
        myUniqueStrings.add(d);
        myUniqueStrings.forEach(item -> System.out.println(item.getName() 
                + " at position " + item.getPosition()));

        System.out.println("———> After having tried to insert an already existing item to the Set:");

        // add an already existing item to the Set
        myUniqueStrings.add(a);
        myUniqueStrings.forEach(item -> System.out.println(item.getName()
                + " at position " + item.getPosition()));
    }
}
```

Note that if you add an `Item` to the `Set` a second time, there will be no change at all.